# Type errors in Angular.io

Tags: angular, http, typescript, observable

Working with Angular2/4 and working on a service, but I'm not sure why this type error keeps coming up. I believe I set my type properly, but that is obviously wrong....

The Error:

```
ERROR in C:/Users/rutherfordc.AA/Documents/GitHub/Sweeper/src/app/people.service.ts (19,12): The type argument for type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred from the usage. Consider specifying the t
ype arguments explicitly.
  Type argument candidate 'Response' is not a valid type argument because it is not a supertype of candidate 'Response'.
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ResponseType'.
```

Here is the code that's causing the error to be thrown according to the error. (additional lines added for completeness.)

```
  person:Person = new Person();
  private dataRetrievalUrl: string = '/api/';
  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  public getPersonById(id: string):Observable<Person>{
    var fullUrl: string = this.dataRetrievalUrl + id;
    return this.http.get(fullUrl)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You have conflicting versions of typings for `Response`, most likely due to importing some library which uses a different version of `@angular/http` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks @torazaburo, completely forgot to import Response at all! gotta get these figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Your `catch` in `.catch(this.handleError);` is changing the return type causing a type mismatch. Hence the error.